# Is there an efficient way to pick out subsets of a set in order of their sum given the original set is sorted?

Tags: matrices, permutations

Let $m$ be a set of positive integers sorted in increasing order. E. g., $m = \langle 3, 7, 11\rangle$. Is there a way to pick in increasing order (and not pick and sort) subsets of $m$ such that after having picked $2^{|m|}$ sets they are in increasing order if we sum them.

For example, I thought this will work. We could generate all binary patterns, i. e., for $|m| = 3$,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0& 0& 0 \\
1& 0& 0 \\
0& 1& 0 \\
1& 1& 0 \\
0& 0& 1 \\
1& 0& 1 \\
0& 1& 1 \\
1& 1& 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
3 \\
7 \\
11
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
3 \\
7 \\
10 \\
11 \\
14 \\
18 \\
21
\end{pmatrix}
$$

But this does not work for $m = \langle3,7,9\rangle$,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0& 0& 0 \\
1& 0& 0 \\
0& 1& 0 \\
1& 1& 0 \\
0& 0& 1 \\
1& 0& 1 \\
0& 1& 1 \\
1& 1& 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
3 \\
7 \\
9
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
3 \\
7 \\
10 \\
9 \leftarrow \text{no!}\\
12 \\
16 \\
19
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Could a binary matrix $X$ of dimensions $(2^{|m|}, |m|)$ with unique rows be generated such that $X\vec{m}$ is sorted if $\vec{m}$ is sorted?

Comment: On the binary matrix question, your examples show that this is impossible, since it if were it would have to be the first matrix that you wrote.

Comment: I don't see how my example proves anything?

Comment: Is $X$ meant to be independent of $m$?

Comment: No, it is not...